"BIN" as part of many paths in an IIS Web Request
I use IIS with a Web API to access information about various resources.  One of the names of one of the resources is "BIN".  I understand and am glad of how IIS protects me from evil-doers that might search for way to invade the "\bin" folder in the app.  But.  I have a resource with the name of BIN and I don't have a choice about its name. And example path sent to the Web API is:
~/api/Search/Find/2001/BIN

The system will search the repository for descriptions of the BIN that are found in the 2001 category.  The response will be a list of topics about the BIN that are in that category.
A minimal controller that exposes the issue is:
namespace Path.Has.Bin.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

/// <summary>
///     An API that might have a "BIN" in the path
/// </summary>
/// <inheritdoc cref="ControllerBase" />
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class Search : ControllerBase
{
    /// <summary>
    ///     An entry that might have a "BIN"
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="targets">a string that might have BIN</param>
    /// <param name="category">a bin that might have BINs</param>
    /// <returns>some string about BINs</returns>
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Find/{category}/{*targets}")]
    public string Find(string targets, string category)
    {
        return targets.Contains("BIN")
            ? $"You seek BINs for {category}"
            : "Bins not sought";
    }
}

A Program.cs:
WebApplicationBuilder builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

WebApplication app = builder.Build();
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
    app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

A project file:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <GenerateDocumentationFile>True</GenerateDocumentationFile>
    <DocumentationFile>.\Path.Has.Bin.Api.Reference.xml</DocumentationFile>
    <GeneratePackageOnBuild>False</GeneratePackageOnBuild>
    <Title>Resource named BIN </Title>
    <Authors>ssailors</Authors>
    <Company>WPC</Company>
    <Description>Can I have a BIN in a URL path?</Description>
    <Copyright>(c) 2024 WPC</Copyright>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.5.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>

Select the IIS Express run profile and the Debug build profile.  Execute the app.  In the Swagger, Try it Out with "BIN" in the targets and anything in the category.  Expect a "You seek ..." but observe a page reporting status 404.8. If you pick the "http" for a Kestrel runtime it will behave as expected.
There are many paths to the many versions of the BIN resource.  I can allow a URL with the configuration/security/requestFiltering/alwayAllowedUrls element in the web.config, adding an entry for each of the paths to the BIN resource.  These paths are versioned, so each new version (once a quarter) the set of paths in the web.config need to be duplicated with new versions.  There are currently 211 <add> elements in this section.  I expect at least 6 more added per year for the life of the project.  I can't predict how long this page will last, but we have been collecting an publishing data since the '70s.  This approach isn't exactly scalable.  Is there a better way to expose the specific BIN resources while maintaining the basic protection against people finding my bin folder?
There is no folder or file in the system named BIN, other than what IIS needs to use for its implementation.  There is a business concept named BIN that the system collect information about.

You can disable that request filtering setting, and instead add a URL Rewrite rule to block access to certain bin folders.

Lex Li, that would be removing the mechanism that Microsoft I'm sure worked very hard to develop and deploy, to replace it with one I write.  I am not sure that would be considered a good idea by my security staff.

The request filtering can be modified to remove the "bin" (as Lex Li suggested in the question comments) and then a location can be added that denies access to everybody.
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <denyUrlSequences>
                    <remove sequence="bin" />
                </denyUrlSequences>
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
    <location path="bin">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <deny users="*" />
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
</configuration>

